# How to Find and Delete Awesomium control from VB project?

Tags: vba

I am working on a program in VB and the Awesomium Webcontrol just glitched out and is missing. I installed a later version of Awesomium. 
Now I try to add a new webcontrol to the form to replace the other one that disappeared and its telling me there is already a control like that in the project but I cant locate it to delete it. 
I am assuming because I installed a newer Awesomium, that when I go to add a new control, the name resets back to webcontrol1 instead of proceeding to the next name in numerical order(Webcontrol2). It wont let me add a new Webcontrol because one with that name already exists. 
Is there a way I can find this missing component or perhaps a way I can rename the new one before I add it to the form?

Comment: Is that a VBA control?  Not heard of it in VBA, and a search is bringing back lots of .Net type results.

Comment: its an SDK i am using in Visual Basic. the one that makes programs on your computer. Not the online stuff.